# How to replace Text in UITextInput?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextinput

I use UITextInput in customView:

MyCode: https://github.com/lequysang/github_zip/blob/master/UITextInputDebug.zip

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) id<UITextInput> textInput;
```

After typing some chars, I want to go back 4 chars and replace text at this position (replace any to  T).Current cursor at the end.

How to do that?

I try replaceRange with UITextRange but don't know how to get position and size with it!

Please help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Insert text at the current cursor location ? sorry I didn't get u..

Comment: I just find insertText method. And "Text" has already inserted. I want back 4 chars and replace at this position.

Comment: have you tried "replaceRange:withText:" ?

Comment: Note: Your `textInput` property should be weak. Strong delegates will likely result in retain cycles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
replaceRange:withText:
```

Replace the text in a document that is in the specified range. (required)

```
- (void)replaceRange:(UITextRange *)range withText:(NSString *)text
```

**Parameters**

```
range
```

A range of text in a document.

```
text
```

A string to replace the text in range.

**Availability**
Available in iOS 3.2 and later.

**See Also**

```
– textInRange:
```

Declared In `UITextInput.h`

Comment: Thanks @Ramshad again!You give me a best way! But I'm stuck to get text position with UITextRange and UITextPosition. Please help you know!